# issue with export and import zipped sql file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a database from server A, and then import it to server B, the sql file is too large, so I want to zip it, for export, there is one option called compression, on the select-list, there are 3 items:zipped, gzipped, bzipped,

Question:

1.what is the different between zipped, gzipped, bzipped? which one should I choose?

2.when I import it to server B, can I just upload the zip file? is there anything i need to do before import or after import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) They are different compression algorithms (for ex : bz and gz have a higher rate of compression then zip but the process is more time consuming) you can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression)
2) Yes you can upload the already compressed file with the condition that the compressed alg is one that the PMA already offers (in your case it is)